# add multiple custom fields to order email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I would like to add 4 custom fields to my woocommerce order emails, but not exactly sure how.  The 4 fields are named 'age' 'year-of-study'  'area-of-interest'  ' vet-school'.  A code snippet would be very useful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too broad, and asking to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code snippet to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'sallar_email_meta_fields', 10, 3 );

function sallar_email_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['age'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Age:' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'age', true ),
    $fields['year-of-study'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Year of study:' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'year-of-study', true ),
    $fields['area-of-interest'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Area of interest:' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'area-of-interest', true ),
    $fields['vet-school'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Vet school:' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'vet-school', true ),
    );
    return $fields;
}
```